# EntityFrameworkCore tracks changes on NoTrackingBehavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

MyContext.cs

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

BaseRepository.cs

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository<TDBEntity> where TDBEntity : class, new()
 {
        protected readonly MyContext dbContext;

        public BaseRepository(MyContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public virtual void Update(TDBEntity model)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public Task CommitAsync()
        {
            return dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
  }
```

If I update the same entity two times, I will get the following error:

```
 The instance of entity type 'Foobar' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.
 When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

I am on a 'connected DbContext scenario' but I don't want any tracking behaviour. I want to use EntityFrameworkCore for 'just' generating SQL-Statements.

Comment: There's no `connected DbContext scenario`. A DbContext is always working disconnected *unless* you open an explicit long-running transaction, which is a generally bad thing to do

Comment: `I want to use EntityFrameworkCore for 'just' generating SQL-Statements.` that's not what it's for. EF is an ORM, not a query generator.

Comment: BTW that "base repository" is an anti pattern and the very reason you have problems. The problems are caused by code you didn't post. What you did post, offers nothing on top of a DbContext except confuse people. `CommitAsync` doesn't commit anything. There's no transaction to commit. It *saves all tracked changes* in an atomic way, by using an internal transaction.

Comment: A DbSet is *already* a repository, a DbContext is *already* a Unit-of-Work. You can fix your perf, correctness and concurrency problems by *removing* the extra classes. Read Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). This is nothing new by the way, people knew you don't need an extra Repository on top of an ORM since 2009: [Repository is the new Singleton](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [`QueryTrackingBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.querytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-5.0) enum docs for `NoTracking` you will see next:

> The change tracker will not track any of the entities that are returned from a LINQ query. If the entity instances are modified, this will not be detected by the change tracker and SaveChanges() will not persist those changes to the database.

So it is responsible for "automatic" change tracking for instances returned by your queries, to do updates and inserts EF still will need to track entities and with `dbContext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;` you attach entity (and all references to other entities which it has as written in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state?redirectedfrom=MSDN#attaching-an-existing-entity-to-the-context)) to context so it starts tracking this entity and marks it as modified.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a tricky thing. I have debugged EF Core sources for several hours to find better way, but with no luck.
Problem that ChangeTracker searches for `EntityEntry` by the reference. If not found by reference it searches by entity keys and if entry found - you have this exception.

So, these extension methods are born. Not super effective even using Internals, but it shows how to do that.

```cs
public static class ChangeTrackerExtensions
{
    public static EntityEntry<T> GetEntry<T>(this DbContext ctx, T entity, out bool isNew) where T : class
    {
        var entityType = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
        var stateManager = ctx.GetService<IStateManager>();

        isNew = false;
        foreach (var key in entityType.GetKeys())
        {
            var keyArray = key.Properties
                .Where(p => p.PropertyInfo != null || p.FieldInfo != null)
                .Select(p =>
                    p.PropertyInfo != null
                        ? p.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity)
                        : p.FieldInfo.GetValue(entity)).ToArray();

            if (keyArray.Length == key.Properties.Count)
            {
                var entry = stateManager.TryGetEntry(key, keyArray);

                if (entry != null)
                {
                    return ctx.Entry((T)entry.Entity);
                }
            }
        }

        isNew = true;
        var newEntry = ctx.Entry(entity);

        return newEntry;
    }

    public static EntityEntry<T> UpdateEntry<T>(this DbContext ctx, T entity) where T : class
    {
        bool isNew;
        var entry = ctx.GetEntry(entity, out isNew);

        if (isNew)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry);
        }
        return entry;
    }
}
```

So, update in your case should looks like

```cs
   public virtual void Update(TDBEntity model)
   {
       dbContext.UpdateEntry(model);
   }
```

Comment: The better way is to ditch the "generic repository' as it's completely unnecessary and *caused* the problem. EF Core isn't broken. None of this code is needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, just forgot about this code ;) I've researched such possibility because of developing library which replaces EF Core LINQ translator. And this was only one way. Also people may want to update the same entity several times because of entities deserialisation.

Comment: But this question isn't about replacing EF Core's translator at all. Besides the translation isn't performed by EF Core, it's performed by the *provider*

Comment: BTW this code has some serious perf issues, because it retrieves the Reflection info for the type every time, even though nothing has changed. At the very least you ned to case the key properties. It's completely inappropriate for this question though - it doesn't fix the actual problem and the OP wouldn't be able to make sense of it

Comment: EF Core is not performing translation... Well theoretically yes, but beside the scenes EF Core performs translation to Query AST and third party providers transforms AST to the SQL - a little work for provider, isn't?.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks that you have missed my words `Not super effective even using Internals`